# SSMS Client Statistics: Total Execution time vs. Real Execution Time?

Tags: performance, execution-time, ssms-2012

In the Client Statistics Window in Sql Server Management Studio, I get the total
execution time.
However, this time is often muss less then the time the query actually took.
So what is the additional time spend for?

For example, here I got ~5,6 seconds of total execution time, but my query took 13 seconds to finish

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The total execution time is the time until the result is available for display. But then, depending on the result set size and the way you display the data, the time until everything has been rendered is usually much higher.